# How to correctly nest list-group with Bootstrap 5.1?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use [Bootstrap 5.1 list group component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/list-group/) to create multi-level list group.

Here is what I did

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h2>Standard</h2>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">First</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Second</a>

    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Level 2 - First</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Level 2 - Second</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<h2 class="mt-5">With Flush</h2>

<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">First</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Second</a>

    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Level 2 - First</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Level 2 - Second</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in the above example, the list group does not look right. How can I fix the nested list-group look?

**Updated**
In the Standard example above, I see spacing issues with the nested menu.

In the Flush example, the bottom line should be the same with in all cases, but the nested level should have a larger indentation.

Comment: The second level of the menu does not seem to fit

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have nested list-groups, also in your Standard example looks good

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom css below for add top and bottom margin of inner list group:

```
.list-group:not(.list-group-flush) .list-group-item .list-group{
    margin-top: .5rem !important;
    margin-bottom: .5rem !important;
}
```

Otherwise, You can use spacing utilities for add [margin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding). Just add `my-2` in inner list-group.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h2>Standard</h2>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">First</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Second</a>

    <ul class="list-group my-2">
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Level 2 - First</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Level 2 - Second</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```